# I'm having trouble including AFRAME in the Asset Pipeline of my Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, three.js, asset-pipeline, aframe, webvr

I want to include [AFRAME](http://aframe.io) into my Rails application. So I downloaded the minified version of aframe and in my Asset Pipe I wrote `\\= require aframe.min.js`

When I try to access my `AFRAME` object, I get an error that is linked to me missing the ThreeJS files associated with A-Frame.

Is there a way to load the [A-Frame js file](https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.2/aframe.min.js) from the cdn's url instead of from my local server?

Comment: Any reason not to just include it in your application.html.erb layout? That's what I've been doing and it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a work around. Here it is:

```
var l=d.createElement('script');
l.setAttribute('src', "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/aframe/0.3.2/aframe.min.js");
h.appendChild(l);
```

And to access `AFRAME` I call `window.AFRAME`